# Change smtp port in AOL server?

Tags: linux, smtp, aol

I need to change smtp port in AOL server how to do this? 
ns_param   mailhost        smtp.yourcompany.com is histting the port 25 by default caould anyone tell me how to change this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use smtpport  parameter.

ns_param smtpport

This is based on the [ns_sendmail proc](http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/Ns_sendmail) .